# React conditional class name setting for styling

Tags: css, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

I am trying to make a quiz app using React.

I am currently working on the main quiz page where I have 4 buttons, and each of the buttons denotes an answer I'm importing from a question bank.

I want the current selected button to be highlighted, and for this I am currently using a state for each button. Is there any way to just use one state and deal with all four of the buttons, as this way is too tedious and cannot be used for a large number of such buttons? Also, I want only one button, the one the user selects finally, to be highlighted. So for this reason I need to set the state of all the other buttons to `null`, which makes the task even more tedious.

Here is the div containing the buttons

```
<div>
  <button className={selected1} onClick={() => dealingWithOptions("A")}>{questions[currentQuestion].optionA}</button>
  <button className={selected2} onClick={() => dealingWithOptions("B")}>{questions[currentQuestion].optionB}</button>
  <button className={selected3} onClick={() => dealingWithOptions("C")}>{questions[currentQuestion].optionC}</button>
  <button className={selected4} onClick={() => dealingWithOptions("D")}>{questions[currentQuestion].optionD}</button>
</div>
```

Here is the function dealing with the options clicking

```
const [selected1,setSelectedButton1] = useState("")
const [selected2,setSelectedButton2] = useState("")
    
const dealingWithOptions = (op) => {
  setOptionChosen(op);
  if (op=="A") {
    setSelectedButton1("selected1"); 
    setSelectedButton2("")
    setSelectedButton3("")
    setSelectedButton4("")
  } else if (op=='B') {
    setSelectedButton1(""); 
    setSelectedButton2("selected2")
    setSelectedButton3("")
    setSelectedButton4("")    
  } else if (op=='C') {
    setSelectedButton1(""); 
    setSelectedButton2("")
    setSelectedButton3("selected3")
    setSelectedButton4("");
  }
  else if (op=='D') {
    setSelectedButton1("");
    setSelectedButton2("")
    setSelectedButton3("")
    setSelectedButton4("selected3");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest having one state, that stores the chosen option (so either A, B, C or D) and then in your JSX part you have a condition that assigns the classname "selected" to the appropiate button.

If the selection changes so will the state, which triggers a rerender (so you don't even have to take away the "selected" class, since it will just be assinged to (and only) the right one on rerender

Comment: I tried your solution and it works perfectly fine, but i dont understand why do the other buttons get re rendered? Is it because in their classname the state we have used is changed? When our state changes does every part involving the state get re rendered?

Comment: @AmanNambisan When the state of a component changes, the whole component get's rerendered. So basically the whole function get's run all over again (assuming you use functional components)

Comment: If you want to get further into how react rerenders there are lots of great resources out there (since React rerenders are a quite basic but really imporant part to understand) I'll link you 2 videos which I myself found helpful (The 2nd is a little more advanced and goes into more depth)
https://youtu.be/4FhJkX18fS8?t=142 and https://youtu.be/i793Qm6kv3U

Answer (score 1):

It can be solved and optimized in many ways. I am trying to give what suit your current code most.

I assume you have a state that stores choosen option.

Now update all the button like this

```
<button className={choosen == "A" ? "selected" : "" } onClick={() => dealingWithOptions("A")}>{questions[currentQuestion].optionA}</button>
```

Here `choosen` is the state where the selected option is being stored.

Explanation: Here what we are doing is, we are matching for each button that if it is the selected button then add the selected class else add nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you set one piece of state to maintain the selected button.

```
setSelectedButton('A')
```

Or undefined if none is selected

Then,

```
<button className={selectedButton === 'A' ? 'selected1' : ''}>...
```

That said for conditional classes I'd use something like `clsx` rather than building class strings manually

e.g.

```
<button className={clsx({selected1: selectedButton === 'A'})}>...
```

Answer (score -1):

Several ways to achieve this.  You can set one state: `const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState("")`
Define the function: `const selectHandler = (e) => setSelectedId(e.target.name)`
On your buttons call the function and set the state to the Id: `<button className={selectedId === "a" && "selected"} name="a" onClick={() => setSelectedId("a")}>Button A</button>` For the rest of the buttons, change the name as well as the parameter passed to the function. Also the string inside the className comparison